# Language bindings "to" or "for" (computing)?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

In computing, one can write *bindings* from one language to another, e.g. *LISP bindings to OpenGL*, or *a collection of bindings for C*.

I seem to find both prepositions *to* and *for* used indiscriminately, even in the Wikipedia [Language bindings page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding), which mentions:

> ... a binding **to** the library must be created in that language...

But also contains a reference to:

> Creating a language binding **for** cairo

The [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Language_bindings) language bindings page also uses both prepositions.

Is there a case in which only one of them is correct? Can I use both indiscriminately?

Answer (score 0):

A language binding **for** a language allows programs written in that language to access a library.

A language binding binds code written in that language **to** the library.